# Get Laravel Validation Keyed By Failed Rules

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm trying to do backend validation in Laravel for a VUE SPA. I'm trying to return errors to the frontend keyed by the actual rule that failed, because my frontend needs to perform some other logic based on what exactly went wrong.

For example, I'd like to get this data structure back:

```
{
"errorMessages": {
    "primary_email": {
        "unique": "Email already exists in SSO."
    },
    "adults": {
        "size": "The adults array must contain 1 item."
    },
    "children": {
        "size": "The children array must contain 2 items."
    }
}
```

Working with the validator, the only structure I can get back is just an array of error messages grouped by field name, or an array of all messages. I can't figure out a way to get a listing of the rules that failed.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validator has method *failed()*, if you try to 'intersect' it with *errors()* you should achieve what you want:

```
$validator = Validator::make ($request->all(), [/* rules*/]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    $errMsgs = [];

    foreach ($validator->errors()->toArray() as $field => $msgs)
        foreach (array_keys($validator->failed()[$field]) as $ind => $errorType)
            $errMsgs['errorMessages'][$field][$errorType] = $msgs[$ind];

}

// dd($errMsgs);
```

Comment: Ah, ok great. I had considered going this route, but I wasn't sure if the messages would be in a consistent order to do an intersect. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewSteenbuck Well, doing some tests it seems that the order is respected, i suggest you to do your own tests e.g. with custom rules also. I haven't found other ways.